# matplotlib plot_trisurf without edges

Tags: matplotlib

Is it possible to plot_trisurf without showing the edges of the triangles at all?
In all the examples:
http://matplotlib.org/dev/examples/mplot3d/trisurf3d_demo2.html
the edges of the triangles are shown.

With the argument edgecolors="none" the edges are still visible.

edit: I meant the rendering artifacts, not the edges, are still visible.

Comment: the link is invalid, please update the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works for me when using `edgecolor='none'`... (Code stolen from the matplotlib demos)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.tri as mtri

# u, v are parameterisation variables
u = (np.linspace(0, 2.0 * np.pi, endpoint=True, num=50) * np.ones((10, 1))).flatten()
v = np.repeat(np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, endpoint=True, num=10), repeats=50).flatten()

# This is the Mobius mapping, taking a u, v pair and returning an x, y, z
# triple
x = (1 + 0.5 * v * np.cos(u / 2.0)) * np.cos(u)
y = (1 + 0.5 * v * np.cos(u / 2.0)) * np.sin(u)
z = 0.5 * v * np.sin(u / 2.0)

# Triangulate parameter space to determine the triangles
tri = mtri.Triangulation(u, v)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(x,y,z,triangles=tri.triangles, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral, edgecolor='none')
```

creates:

[image]

The remaining edge ghosts are rendering artifacts. Are they a problem?

Comment: Is there a way to remove the rendering artifacts?

Comment: Yes, there is. You will have to give each triangle an edge color which is the same as the fill color of the triangle.

Comment: @DrV How exactly does one go about setting the triangle edge colors? I am having a similar problem and posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727277/setting-edgecolor-to-match-facecolor-in-trisurf).

Answer (score 6):

For me a combination of [DrV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3735428/drv) and [AnandJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5754120/anandj) is working with specifying

1. an `edgecolor='none'`,
2. a `linewidth=0` and
3. setting `antialiased=False` also.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass linewidth argument to plot_trisurf to make edges disappear:

```
ax.plot_trisurf(x,y,z,triangles=tri.triangles, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```