# Matplotlib: How to remove guidelines in trisurf (3D surface)

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, surface

I want to eliminate those white triangle-shaped lines in my plot but I dont know how. Thanks

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
surf = ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, shade=False, linewidth=1)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_title('Plot')

plt.show()
```

[image: This is my plot output]

Comment: `ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, linewidth=0, shade=False, facecolor='skyblue',  edgecolor='none', antialiased=False)` see [matplotlib plot_trisurf without edges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46705320/12046409)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib plot\_trisurf without edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476344/matplotlib-plot-trisurf-without-edges)

Comment: @JohanC: If your comment solved the problem, write it as an answer.

Comment: @PeterO. It is  a simple duplicate.  Also, the question is lacking example data making an answer rather uninformative.