# plot_trisurf is always semi transparent

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using `matplotlib` to plot 3D triangulated surface. However even if didn't define any alpha value the plot is semi transparent. I would like to make it completely opaque.

`dataset` is the array storing the mesh information.

```
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize()
fvalue=np.zeros(np.size(dataset.tri,0))

for i in range(0,np.size(dataset.tri,0)):
    tri=dataset.tri[i]
    fvalue[i]=dataset.var['T'][0,int(tri[0])]
colors = custom_colormap(norm(fvalue))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
p3dc = ax.plot_trisurf(dataset.coord[0], dataset.coord[1],dataset.coord[2], triangles=dataset.tri)
p3dc.set_fc(colors)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39144482/7758804

Comment: Seems so this is a bug with no solution?

Comment: Matplotlib's 3d capabilities are limited, e.g. it uses a layered approach to mask hidden parts. Further, `plot_trisurf` is meant to draw a surface where the height z is a function of x and y, so it doesn't really support closed surfaces.  The matplotlib documentation suggests looking into the Mayavi library if you need better 3d quality.

Comment: Did you try `edgecolor='none', linewidth=0, antialiased=False` as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476344/matplotlib-plot-trisurf-without-edges)?

Comment: Yes but it cause not smooth surfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to result from incorrectly using the axes method `set_fc` (set_facecolor) instead of `set_color`.  The `set_color` method assigns both edge and face colors.  The example below illustrates the difference:

[image: set color comparison]

where the code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import s3dlib.surface as s3d

# create dataset ................................................
class data :
    def __init__(self) :
        def varT(rtp) :
            x,y,z = s3d.SphericalSurface.coor_convert(rtp,True)
            return -np.cos(2*(z+1)*np.pi)         
        surface = s3d.SphericalSurface(5)
        surface.map_cmap_from_op(varT,cmap='seismic')
        self.coord = surface.vertexCoor.T
        self.tri = surface.fvIndices
        self.colors = surface.facecolors

dataset = data()

# show figure, comparing set_facecolor to set_color .............
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,3))

ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
ax.set_title("set_facecolor")
p3dc = ax.plot_trisurf(dataset.coord[0], dataset.coord[1],dataset.coord[2], triangles=dataset.tri)
p3dc.set_facecolor(dataset.colors)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
ax2.set_title("set_color")
p3dc = ax2.plot_trisurf(dataset.coord[0], dataset.coord[1],dataset.coord[2], triangles=dataset.tri)
p3dc.set_color(dataset.colors)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

There seems a lot of discussions regarding this problem.  The problem is not Matplotlib rendering, but an insufficient  explanation in the Matplotlib documentation regarding color, facecolor, edgecolor and linewidth.  These properties interact to create the resulting visualization. This problen even gets worse when transparent surfaces are used.  A further discussion of this rendering 'artifact' is in the [S3Dlib](https://s3dlib.org/guides/guides/face_edge.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this in fact solves this issue. As an alternative, I switched to pyvista which is much more robust.